Error bulk writing to Milvus vector database
I'm trying to bulk write entries to my Milvus database but I get an error:
new parquet reader failed, err=parquet: could not retrieve footer offset: The specified key does not exist.: importing data failed

The relevant lines of code are:
client = MilvusClient(uri="http://localhost:19530")

# omitting code for brevity...

writer = LocalBulkWriter( schema=schema,local_path='.',segment_size=5*1024 * 1024 * 1024, file_type=BulkFileType.PARQUET)
for i in tqdm(range(len(sku))):
  writer.append_row({"sku": str(sku[i])[:128], "vec":vectors[i],"title": str(title[i])[:512]})
  writer.commit()

# ...

os.system("""
export MILVUS_URI="localhost:19530"
curl --request POST "http://${MILVUS_URI}/v2/vectordb/jobs/import/get_progress"
--header "Content-Type: application/json"
--data-raw '{
"jobId": "~"
}'
""")

